# Cannot go back - popViewControllerAnimated not working, swipe back not working too

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am new to iOS development. I created a segue from one VC to another VC. It is set as "Show(e.g. Push)"

[image]

However, swipe back capability is not working. Also, I have a custom back button. I have set a listener to it, which also does nothing:

```
@IBAction func backClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

What is wrong? I want back button to work and swipe back capability to also work. I don't need Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Embed In navigation controller to your root view controller and hide your navigation bar if you don't need it. And your button action will work.

Comment: yey, got it to work, thanks bro, I appreciate people like you ;)

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Comment: The demo was removed, could you repost it please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my project used split view controller. I removed it, and `popViewController` worked.